# access individual items from numpy data type

Tags: numpy

if I create a data type in numpy to load a txt file like

```
nameData = np.dtype([('Name',str),('Group',str),('Income',np.float)])
dataMat = np.loadtxt(fname,dtype=nameData)
```

I want to access all the groups but dataMat[:,1] does not seem to work. What is the best way to get all the groups?

Comment: Why does `dataMat[:,1]` not work?

Comment: `dataMat['Group']`, `dataMat['Income'].  Access the fields by field name.  This is a 1d array with a compound dtype - a structured array.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: @hpaulj Cool, I think that's an answer.

Comment: @hpaulj Is there a way I can check if the 2nd element in the group string if a digit - like for example dataMat['Group',1].isdigit()

Comment: `dataMat['Group'][1]` is that string.